# How to select rows where date is greater than the date in another row?

Tags: sql, db2

I have a table with customer cards. A customer can have several cards. For every customer card there is one row. If a customer has several cards, there are several rows. There are  two different card types A and B. For every card the `last_used` date is stored.

I want to check if there are customers with both customer cards of type A *and* B, where the last_used date of card B is younger then the last_used date of card A.

This is my table CUSTOMER_CARDS.

```
card_id | customer_id | card_type | last_used
----------------------------------------------
      1 |          c1 |         A | 2017-07-07
      2 |          c1 |         B | 2016-04-01
      3 |          c2 |         A | 2017-06-04
      4 |          c2 |         B | 2017-07-03
      5 |          c3 |         A | 2016-02-23
      6 |          c3 |         B | 2017-04-17
```

I need a select statement which selects the `customer_id` of customer `c2`, who has a card of type B which is younger then his cards of type A. How do I achieve this?

Comment: With that sample table data, what is the expected result? (As formatted text.)

Comment: A list of customer_ids. In this example it would be `c2`.

Comment: @htz - How `c2` because type = `B` is having greater `last_used` than `A`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need `Group By` and `Having` clause

```
select customer_id
from yourtable
Group by customer_id
Having Min(case when card_type = 'B' then last_used end) >  Max(case when card_type = 'A' then last_used end)
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you try something like this?

```
SELECT A.card_id, A.customer_id, A.card_type, A.last_used 
FROM CUSTOMER_CARDS A
INNER JOIN CUSTOMER_CARDS B ON A.customer_id=B.customer_id
WHERE A.card_type='B'
    AND B.card_type='A' AND A.last_user > B.last_used
    ;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select d1.cusid,d1.cardtyp,d1.lstusd 
from democat d1 
join democat d2 on d1.cusid = d2.cusid 
where d1.lstusd < d2.lstusd and d1.cardtyp = 'B'
```